# Euclidean norm of complex vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, bilinear-form

I am working on a proof: One has two vectors, $u,v \in \mathbb C^n$, such that $u \cdot v=0$ . I am trying to prove that

> $$|u + v|^2 = |u|^2 + |v|^2.$$

I am a little stuck on how to do $u + v$ dotted with the conjugate of $u + v$. Is there anything special I can do with this?

Comment: @Bye_World: The question was edited after my comment was added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how.

> $$ ||u+v||^2  = \langle u+v,u+v \rangle = \langle u,u \rangle +  \langle v,v \rangle +  \langle u,v \rangle +  \langle v,u \rangle  = ||u||^2+||v||^2 +0+0.  $$

**Note:**

> $$  \langle u,v \rangle = u \cdot v  $$

Answer (score 0):

$|u+v|^2 = \langle u+v,u+v\rangle = \langle u,u\rangle + 0 + 0 + \langle v,v \rangle  = |u|^2 + |v|^2$

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle for $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$